# The headers can't be found by gcc

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I have included the header file in each source file,but it fails to find them when I use`make`command. These header files included are simple and located in the same project directory.

```
In file included from tests/list_tests.c:1:
tests/minunit.h:6:10: fatal error: dbg.h: No such file or directory
    6 | #include "dbg.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Below are all the project files:
[code in github](https://github.com/LeenOlll/liblcthw)

I have tried to add`-I *PATH*` to gcc but it fails to find files either. And I add PATH to .bashrc then use`make`,it also can't find files.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text, post text as properly formatted text. And don't post links to external source code, your question should me self contained. Read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]

Comment: That's not an issue with Make. The option `-I` is not recursive. Just because you included the headers in `src/` it doesn't mean GCC will also consider the headers in `src/lcthdw`.

Comment: As above.  But just to note, the `PATH` environment variable is used to find _programs_ that you want to run from the command line (like `ls` or `mkdir` or your compiler or `make` itself).  It's not searched for other kinds of files (especially not things like header files used during compilation).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You use `-Isrc`, but the file `dbg.h` is in the directory `src/lcthdw`. Change the directory for the `-I` flag (or add another `-I` flag with the `src/lcthdw` directory).